# Combining CSV and shapefile to find area name where stations are located

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, spatial-join, point-in-polygon

I have one shapefile with marine areas. The other is a CSV file with some station names and coordinates. I would like to get table with stations names and corresponding marine area names, where the stations are located.

Is there an easy way to do this in QGIS? (for example using Field Calculator or Attribute Table).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using PyQGIS.

Let's assume there is a project folder with two files: `'test_points.csv'` and `'test_polygons.shp'`, see image below.

[image: input]

In QGIS they will look like

[image: qgis]

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and copy&edit&paste the script below

```py
# defining inputs
project_path = 'C:/Users/DUBRTARA/Desktop/test/project/'
csv_file_name = 'test_points.csv'
shp_file_name = 'test_polygons.shp'

# Step 1: reading a csv file with points and converting it into a shapefile
uri_csv_file = 'file:///' + project_path + csv_file_name + "?encoding={0}&delimiter={1}&xField={2}&yField={3}&crs={4}".format("UTF-8",",","x","y","epsg:31469")
# In .format("UTF-8",",","x","y","epsg:31469")
# "UTF-8" stands for data encoding (optional)
# "," is a delimiter used in the input file
# xField is a column name for longitude value
# yField is a column name for latitude value
# crs is a Coordinate system in EPSG number
points = QgsVectorLayer(uri_csv_file, '', "delimitedtext")
if not points.isValid():
    print ("{} layer was not loaded".format(csv_file_name))

# Step 2: reading a shapefile with polygons
path_to_shp_file_name = project_path + shp_file_name
polygons = QgsVectorLayer(path_to_shp_file_name, '', "ogr")
if not polygons.isValid():
    print ("{} layer was not loaded".format(shp_file_name))
    
# Step 3: joining attributes by location and adding it into the QGIS's main window
processing.runAndLoadResults('qgis:joinattributesbylocation', {
                                                'INPUT':points,
                                                'JOIN':polygons,
                                                'DISCARD_NONMATCHING':False,
                                                'JOIN_FIELDS':[],
                                                'METHOD':0,
                                                'PREDICATE':0,
                                                'PREFIX':'_',
                                                'OUTPUT':'memory:'})
# for more details run the following command >>> processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:joinattributesbylocation")
```

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [Geodose | Python QGIS Tutorial: Adding CSV Data](https://www.geodose.com/2018/07/python-qgis-tutorial-adding-csv-data.html)
- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook » 3. Loading Layers](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#loading-layers)
- [QGIS Docs » 23.1.14.15. Join attributes by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location)
- [PyQGIS 101: Running Processing tools](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-running-processing-tools/)

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for sharing! I am currently taking Python e-course from Coursera.org. Python combined with GIS is my ultimate goal.

Answer (score 7):

Step 1: [Load the CSV](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html?highlight=load%20csv#importing-a-delimited-text-file) into QGIS.

Step 2: Use `join attributes by location` to add the marine area names to the point data (thus, first layer in dialogue is the stations, second the marine areas).

Step 3: Save your created data & table.

Comment: Superb :D thank you!